# An Unexpected value changed in JavaScript while solving Maximum Subarray with Divide & Conquer Approach

Tags: javascript, python

I am trying to solve LeetCode problem [53. Maximum Subarray](https://leetcode.com/problems/maximum-subarray/description/):

> Given an integer array nums, find the subarray which has the largest sum and return its sum.

Here is my failing attempt:

```js
/**
 * @param {number[]} nums
 * @return {number}
 */
var maxSubArray = function(nums) {
    function mergeSort(all, left, right) {
        if ( left > right ) {
            return Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
        }
        const mid = Math.floor((left + right) / 2);
        let leftSum = rightSum = currentSum = 0;
        // sum the left side
        for (i = mid - 1; i >= left; i -= 1) {
            currentSum = currentSum + all[i];
            leftSum = Math.max(leftSum, currentSum);
        }
        currentSum = 0;
        for (i = mid + 1; i <= right; i += 1) {
            currentSum = currentSum + all[i];
            rightSum = Math.max(rightSum, currentSum);
        }
        // compare the value and find the max among the left, the right and the middle0
        const result = Math.max(mergeSort(all, left, mid - 1), 
                                mergeSort(all, mid + 1, right), 
                                leftSum + all[mid] + rightSum);
        return result
    }
    return mergeSort(nums, 0, nums.length - 1);
};

const nums =[-2,1,-3,4,-1,2,1,-5,4];
console.log(maxSubArray(nums)); // 4 ????
```

It seems somehow values change on `leftSum` and `rightSum` if I assign them directly as `leftSum + all[mid] + rightSum` to `Math.max(...)`.

With the input `nums =[-2,1,-3,4,-1,2,1,-5,4]`, the expected return is 6. However, I will get 4 as you can see when running the snippet above.

The cause seems that I don't store `leftSum + all[mid] + rightSum` in a variable first -- `middlePart` -- like in this version:

```js
/**
 * @param {number[]} nums
 * @return {number}
 */
var maxSubArray = function(nums) {
    function mergeSort(all, left, right) {
        if ( left > right ) {
            return Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
        }
        const mid = Math.floor((left + right) / 2);
        let leftSum = rightSum = currentSum = 0;
        // sum the left side
        for (i = mid - 1; i >= left; i -= 1) {
            currentSum = currentSum + all[i];
            leftSum = Math.max(leftSum, currentSum);
        }
        currentSum = 0;
        for (i = mid + 1; i <= right; i += 1) {
            currentSum = currentSum + all[i];
            rightSum = Math.max(rightSum, currentSum);
        }
        // compare the value and find the max among the left, the right and the middle0
        const middlePart = leftSum + all[mid] + rightSum;
        const result = Math.max(mergeSort(all, left, mid - 1), 
                                mergeSort(all, mid + 1, right), 
                                middlePart);
        return result
    }
    return mergeSort(nums, 0, nums.length - 1);
};

const nums =[-2,1,-3,4,-1,2,1,-5,4];
console.log(maxSubArray(nums)); // 6 (good!)
```

That version of the code works, as I extract the part that should cause problem to a single variable.

Does this issue come out from the ECMAScript specification, or what have I messed up?

I wrote this code inspired by [a solution in Python](https://leetcode.com/problems/maximum-subarray/solutions/1595195/c-python-7-simple-solutions-w-explanation-brute-force-dp-kadane-divide-conquer/)

```py
class Solution:
    def maxSubArray(self, nums):
        def maxSubArray(A, L, R):
            if L > R: return -inf
            mid, left_sum, right_sum, cur_sum = (L + R) // 2, 0, 0, 0
            for i in range(mid-1, L-1, -1):
                left_sum = max(left_sum, cur_sum := cur_sum + A[i])
            cur_sum = 0
            for i in range(mid+1, R+1):
                right_sum = max(right_sum, cur_sum := cur_sum + A[i])
            return max(maxSubArray(A, L, mid-1),
                   maxSubArray(A, mid+1, R),
                   left_sum + A[mid] + right_sum)
        return maxSubArray(nums, 0, len(nums)-1)
```

In my perspective, it's an implementation of [this divide and conquer concept](https://afteracademy.com/blog/divide-and-conquer-approach-in-programming).

I tried printing out the left, right, mid, leftSum, rightSum, and the `i` (index) from both JavaScript and Python to compare them. The only difference I found was when printing:

- JavaScript:

  ```
  mergeSort(all, left, mid - 1), 
  mergeSort(all, mid + 1, right), 
  leftSum + all[mid] + rightSum
  ```
- Python:

  ```py
  maxSubArray(A, L, mid-1), 
  maxSubArray(A, mid+1, R), 
  left_sum + A[mid] + right_sum
  ```

The last expression will be different...

Comment: Declare your variables in JS. Not sure if that's the exact problem you have, but I think it's highly likely.

Comment: @VLAZ Yes, that will make it work for me. I just don't get it. Why does declare it as a single variable make the value different. Or I should say, why the value would be changed. Does it regard to the memory, calculation mechanism, something I don't know about JavaScript?

Comment: If you don't *declare* a variable, it's an implicit global. Using the same values across all function executions is quite obviously not the same as having different ones.

Comment: @YPChen, can you include a runnable snippet in your question that outputs 4 when we run it? (Use toolbar button to create it in the editor)

Comment: @trincot Yes, I just added the snippets, many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because this doesn't *declare* all three variables:

```
        let leftSum = rightSum = currentSum = 0;
```

This implicitly defines the second and third variables as globals.

It should be:

```
        let leftSum = 0, rightSum = 0, currentSum = 0;
```

This difference matters when the expression `leftSum + all[mid] + rightSum` is only evaluated **after** the recursive calls have been made (as is the case when you don't first store that result in a variable, but pass it as **last** argument). In that case the recursive calls influence the result of that expression as they modify the values of the same global variables.

You should also define `i` explicitly.

I would advise you to use "use strict" so that such errors are reported.

Comment: Wow! But why it did make it work as by declaring a `middlePart`. Would that be an NaN, and causing errors?

Comment: I added a paragraph about that in my answer.

Comment: Now I got the point. Thank you very much! I put much focus on modifying it from Python...feel nothing but that I don't know JavaScript.

Comment: This aspect will not play a role anymore if you start your JS scripts consistently with the `"use strict"` directive.  Then your first attempt would not have compiled. Python is more strict in that it doesn't allow you to assign to global names *unless* you explicitly allow it with `global` or `nonlocal` (whichever applies), and otherwise it defines names as locals upon first use (contrary to non-strict-mode JS).